# What is the best way to store big data and create instant search with ES?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, bigdata, database

I am working on a project that will store million of data per day. So I want to store it in compressed structure(only searchable field and removing unwanted fields) to elastic search for instant text search. But I want the uncompressed data to be stored for later process and analytics. it should have more write speed and Cheaper to store billions of data.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch allows you to decide, per index, where to store it (via [shard allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html)) and what kind of compression you would like to use (via [index codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html)).

So with unlimited resources and time, you could design a process where you index documents into daily indices for example, on a 5 node cluster where you keep the last 7 days on 3 of the servers (let's call these the fast servers) and anything older than that will be kept on the 2 slower servers, that way queries ranged on the last 7 days will run faster while jobs that are not time-sensitive can run on the older indices which are stored on the slower servers.

The fast servers could have more computing power and faster SSD disks while the slower servers will have normal spinning disks.

Regarding compression, Elasticsearch compression works on the _source data, so compression should not affect aggregation speed, its also important to note that if you change the index compression it will only apply to new/updated documents and will not run retroactively on documents that you've indexed in the past.

Comment: But you still not telling about the primary storage of content. I am using elastic search only for searching the text. so I will add the only searchable content to it,the main content  needs to be stored somewhere and it should not cost much. But it should be retrievable for further process and analytics.